# Decryping a RAR file with same password

Tags: encryption, file-encryption, compression

I came across a problem very similar recently and wondered if anyone knew how to solve this.

So say for example I have an RAR archive called archiveA.rar and a password to protect it the password is known as keyA.  keyA is stored on the server but I can send the server any file and it will compress it into a RAR file and encrypt it with keyA.  I can keep sending files to the server to retrieve encrypted versions of different files.  So my question is with all this given information and the fact that I can send unlimited files to the server can I solve for keyA, if so please explain how I would do so?

Comment: Could you explain why are you asking specifically about RAR?

Comment: Because the scenario I was in recently was dealing with a RAR, and I can't seem to find any resources on how RAR files are encrypted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RAR uses AES256 for encryption<sup>[source](http://www.rarlab.com/rar_archiver.htm)</sup>, thus the question is whether [AES](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) is cryptographically resistant to a [known-plaintext attack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack).

At present there is no known method that allows retrieving AES encryption key given unlimited number of plaintext inputs and corresponding outputs faster than brute-force. Although there is no proof that it is impossible.

See [related posts](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1512/32168) on Cryptography SE.

Comment: thanks a bunch for helping me understand this concept :)